Configure samba share to be accessible by userA but all files/folders created should be owned by userB
I have a share data with valid users = userA.
[data]
    path = /path/to/share
    guest ok = no
    browseable = yes
    valid users = "userA"
    read only = no

/path/to/share is owned by userB. I want it so when someone connects to this samba share as userA, all the files/folders they create, an their general permissions, are tied to userB.
I can't use sticky bit on /path/to/share. I'm looking for a samba config way to do this.

Formally, what you're looking for, is the force user directive, so one user subset is allowed to login to some share, and the actual id will be given as they are some other particular user.
But I should warn you that this is a very lousy way to organize your shares: basically you should organize the AAA model in a way when the actual access to files is given based on their permissions from a filesystem, say, using POSIX ACLs, and in configuration file you should only specify the authorization method and/or of very vague access limiting for some user subset. Strictly assigning userdIDs from force user or force group (as well as using valid users) is one-way ticket to a poorly configured Samba.

What does AAA mean? I don't get the rest of what you said. I want a user to have write access to a specific share/folder, but I want all files they create to be owned by another user. I could add userB to the group of userA but I'd rather avoid that.

Authentication-And-Authorization

Got it. Can you explain more by what you mean by all that?
